# Laravel query scope, get record with max effective date when premium id is same

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

if I have two records with same premium id I want to get only one record which has max effective date.
Below are the sample records

[image: ar]

I have tried using

```
public function scopeEffectiveDate($query)
    {
        $current_date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        return $query->where(max('effective_date'), '<=', $current_date);
    } // shows error
```

and

```
public function scopeEffectiveDate($query)
    {
        $current_date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        return $query->groupBy('insurance_provider_id')->latest('effective_date')->where('effective_date', '<=', $current_date);
    }
```

I am getting one result but not with the latest effective date, it is taking the wrong one.

Comment: Do you need to check effective date is not from current DateTime?

Comment: try this one  $query->groupBy('insurance_provider_id')->latest('effective_date')->where('effective_date', '<=', $current_date)->distinct('column_name');

Comment: @SaadSuri `effective_date <= $current_date` as specified in question

Comment: @PrinceKumarDwivedi I tried, it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code

```
public function scopeEffectiveDate($query)
{
    $current_date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    return $query->orderBy('effective_date', 'desc')->where('effective_date', '<=', $current_date);
}
```

Comment: I do not think it will work as if he will use group by effective_date, he may get same insurance_provider with different effective_date.